# On iOS, why does no such property exist when ViewController's view is set to my UIView subclass?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

If a subclass is defined as `MyView` that subclasses `UIView`, and in the Interface Builder, the view is clicked on, and the Custom Class is already set to `MyView`.

But in ViewController's `viewDidLoad`,

```
 self.view.foo = ... ;
```

will create a compile error that says `foo` is not a property of `UIView`.  I then print out the class of `self.view`:

```
NSLog(@"Class of view is %@", NSStringFromClass([self.view class]));
```

and sure enough, it prints out `MyView`.  Also, not only the first line will not compile, Xcode will not "auto complete" the word "foo" as well.  But clearly, the class prints out no as `UIView` but is `MyView`, and in my class definition of `MyView`, I did say:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *foo;
```

in the interface `.h` file, and also in the implementation `.m` file:

```
@synthesize foo;
```

and `MyView.h` is imported in `ViewController.h` as well.  Why is this so and how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your UIViewController doesn't know that its view is meant to be an instance of your `MyView` subclass.

You'll need to cast it

```
MyView *myView = (MyView *)self.view;
myView.foo = @"Whatever";
```

If you want to simplify this, you can also subclass UIViewController and then just always reference `self.myView` in your MyViewController subclasses instead of `self.view`:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) MyView *myView;

@end


@implementation MyViewController
@synthesize myView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
            self.myView = (MyView *)self.view;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: will need such casting every single time?  that's quite troublesome... also I tried defining my own `view` method in the ViewController that returns `(MyView *)` and the code does `return (MyView *) super.view;` but still... Xcode won't autocomplete and will still complain no such property for `UIView`

Comment: -(MyView*)getView { return (MyView*)self.view; }   That didn't work?

Comment: You need to redefine the `view` property in your UIViewController subclass, to be of your specific subclass, if you are going to use self.view a lot and want to avoid casting.

Comment: @JoshHudnall - made my comment obsolete whilst I was typing it, nice one!

Comment: @jrturton :) We were definitely headed in the same direction.

Comment: @Josh and @jrturton there is no way to still call it `self.view`?  (must be another name, such as `self.myView`?  And I think we can modify `ViewController.m` since it is already a subclass of `UIViewController`?

Comment: You probably can, but take the example of UITableViewController - the view property there is always a table view, but this is accessed via the `tableView` property. It's clearer when reading the code.

Comment: @JeremyL Check out this SO answer and give it a spin. It may be a way for you to keep the same variable name by using a different backing variable in your subclass. (I just learned about this.) http://stackoverflow.com/a/10770673/350467